# Selenium moveToElement twice and then click on element is not working

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mouseover

There is an element on which I need to click after mouseover on two elements i.e. mouseover on Element1-> mouseover on Element2-> click on Element3.

Below is my code:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(billingBtn).build().perform();
actions.moveToElement(billingconfigurationBtn).build().perform();
actions.moveToElement(billingcyclemanagementBtn).click().build().perform();
```

This is not working for me. It executes so fast, then it is able to perform only 1st step.

Please help!

Comment: Could you try creating the entire `Action` chain before calling `.build().perform()`? Eg. `actions.moveToElement(billingBtn).moveToElement(...).moveToElement(...).click().build().perform();`

Comment: @RemcoW: Tried. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

If the Hover over event on Element 2 depends on appearance of Some Element which appears after Mouse over on Element 1 then the Mouse over action on Element 1 and in next statement Mouse over element on Element 2 might not be able to detect if the mouse was hovered over the Element 1 or not as it is executing fast


try to do 
Mouse Over Element 1
Webdriver wait for some element appearing after hover on Element 1 
Mouse Over Element 2
Webdriver wait for some element appearing after hover on Element 2 
Click on the desired element

Comment: We have tried with new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element)); for all 3 elements. But, no luck.

Comment: Does the elements show some hover text after the mouse is hovered onto the elements. If it show then it would be good to wait for the hover text to be displayed, which will confirm that mouse was hovered on to the desired elements

Comment: Yeah. Good idea. But there is no hover text on any element.